# How can I bring the fixed size picture from Photo library to UIImagePickerController?

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller

How can I bring the fixed size picture from Photo library to UIImagePickerController?

My current implementation:

```
func pickPhotoFromGallery(){
    var picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as! String]
    self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: what you want to do with that image? if you want to show it in imageview you can get the image and set the frame you want else if you want some other case for sending etc you can resize the picture after you select it

Comment: I need to bring only 1920*1080 size photos!